# How to prove that 3D lines given by their equations are noncoplanar

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

$(R^3,(R^3,q_0),φ)$ 
[picture for the $(R^3,(R^3,q_0),φ)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR1a1.png)

$D_1: \ x_1-3=x_2/2=(x_3-1)/3 $

$D_2: \ x_1=x_2/2=x_3$

Q: Is it true $D_1,D_2$ are noncoplanar ? If yes, why ?

Hi! Has anybody an idea about a formula I should use or an advice on how to proceed ?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your mathematical expressions.

Comment: Hint: What does the point-normal form of the equation of a plane about the relationship between the normal and every point on the plane?

Comment: I don't understand your $x$ in $x-3=...$. Is it $x_3= $ ? Could you correct it ? Neither I understand what you mean with $(R^3,(R^3,q0),φ) $ ?

Comment: I have bettered your presentation that will learn you some Latex basics ; I have also taken the liberty to provide a new title, in order that it reflects the content of your question.

Comment: Thx for the changes @JeanMarie , the x in x-3 should have been x1-3 , typo mistake, sorry.

Comment: I see I have been downvoted... for an exact answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that their direction vectors are different. It follows that they cannot be parallel. Then note that they never intersect.

The two facts above imply they are skew. Thus, they cannot be coplanar.

Comment: "Then note they never intersect" ??? You haven't proved anything !

Comment: @JeanMarie *You haven't proved anything!* We don't typically do people's work for them here, especially if it's a trivial observation as seeing that those lines do not intersect. As for your claim that the lines are parallel. Well, I simply don't know what to say to that than to repeat that you note their direction vectors.

Comment: Two things : 1) I maintain that your affirmation "they never intersect" is based on nothing ; moreover, I dislike adjective "trivial" : it is sometimes used as an excuse for hiding misunderstanding and in all cases it appears very contemptuous to people to which it is addressed. 2) But I honestly recognize that I had made an error : the projection of two 3D lines can be parallel without the lines being parallel (which is the case here).

Comment: @JeanMarie It is not based on nothing. Please don't be ridiculous. That I don't explicitly show all the work in answering a question doesn't mean I don't know or have not done such work (which again here is trivial if you've tried to solve the resultant equations from assuming the lines intersect).

Comment: @JeanMarie PS. When you delete your comment on parallelism and leave only the other, you make the situation look differently to those who don't know the story from the beginning or who don't have enough reputation to see the true development of things. That's in fact *dishonest.* Also, trying to maintain a spurious claim is also dishonest when the fact is that the work here is easy to do. Also, not taking the hasty advice you'd officiously given me in your deleted comment yourself (after mistakenly discovering you were wrong) shows triply how actually dishonest you're being here, contrary...

Comment: @JeanMarie ...to what you would have us think by using the word *honestly* in a very unnecessary & showy manner. Also, it's very hypocritical of you to blame others for something and then do exactly that. Well, I don't use the word trivial for the funny reasons you cite (perhaps that's how *you* use that word, and are merely projecting); I use it when things are actually trivial, which they are here. But I see that it's all a projection of your mind. I really don't know what motivated your attempts to discredit my answer (which is obviously more helpful than yours), but not only you can talk!

Answer (score -1):

They cannot intersect because there cannot exist a common point $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to them ; indeed, it should verify the different relationships.

But the two first equalities are already incompatible : it is not possible that coordinates $(x_1,x_2)$ verify simultaneously :

$$x_1-3=x_2/2 \ \ \text{and} \ \ x_1=x_2/2\tag{1}$$

It would mean that $x_1-3=x_1$...

(Please note that we haven't used $x_3$ for obtaining the impossibility of a common point).